# SAP GUI Scripting: automate the Opening of XML

Tags: vba, scripting, interaction, sap-gui

I'm trying to automate the opening of the XML File with my SAP GUI Script (see the picture below). But I don't know how to write this step in my SAP GUI script. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank you

Popup contents in English:

> Open XML 
>
> Please select the format in which you want to open this file 
> Please select how you would like to open the file 
> (o) As an XML table 
> (  ) As a read-only workbook  
> (  ) Use the XML Source task pane

Popup contents in German:

> XML Offnen 
>
> Bitte wählen das Format, in dem Sie die Datei öffnen möchten:
> (o) Als XML-Tabelle 
> (  ) Als eine schreibgeschützte Arbeitsmappe 
> (  ) Aufgabenbereich "XML-Quelle" verwenden

[image]

Comment: I guess it's a SAP GUI screen. Please use the SAP GUI Script recorder to record the action you want to execute.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I already tried to record this action but the problem is, after the opening of this popup, the recorder stop to record this step ( clicken on "OK") and realy don't know how to record or automate this step! I hope you understood my problem :)

Comment: Weird. Is this popup really a window coming from SAP GUI, or from Windows, or from another software? If it's not SAP GUI, you can find some software to automate user actions in any software.

Comment: This is what i'm trying to find out. The SAP GUI Script is running (clicking the Button top left) until the Windows pop up, i guess it's a Microsoft excel Window. but i'm not sure. :(

Comment: Could you translate what this text means, and then search if other people explained how to avoid this popup?

Comment: This popup shows/ask to choise in which format you want to open you data File ( XMLFile , .txt or excel) not more.